# Grabbing the user input from a textbox (after said box had that in it)

Tags: c#

after searching for a while i cant find an answer so im asking here to see if you guys can give me a hand on what i need to use:

I have a textbox that is showing data from a db, but the user is able to modify it, and submit the changes (so it changes the data in the DB), the thing is, when he submits it, the program is grabbing the data before the user modify it (the db data) not the new data that the user wrote.

how can i make it so that it grabs the user data instead of the db data?

code there isnt much to show, im using the .Text to get the data from the TextBox1

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Datos obj = new Datos();
    String provi = DropDownList2.Text;
    String dataSet1 = obj.Mostrar_Campos(provi, "Select patron from t_tipo_formato where        id =");
    TextBox1.Text = dataSet1;  //this is the box where the user can make changes
```

This one is the one that runs after the user made changes and click the new button

```
protected void New(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Datos objeto = new Datos();
    objeto.Create_Entry(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text);
    Response.Redirect("http://localhost:4233/WebSite3/Formato.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Besides terrible naming (`obj`, `dataSet1`, `DropDownList2`), what seems to be the problem? Can you post the code for the `Datos`? (and even though it's spanish/italian, `objeto` is still object and quite unclear and it's meaning as a variable)

Comment: dont worry, fix it already, only needed request.params

Comment: Good. Either mark as answered, or delete if you think it wouldn't be relevant to others :).

Comment: will do, when the system allow me to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Request.Params[]` solved it.